# Update app to play store second time using flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have created an app using Android Studio and uploaded it to Play Store. Now I want to update the project using flutter. Is this possible to upload generated app from flutter to play store?

Comment: yeah, You can upload apk generated with flutter, remember to use the same signing key and correct versionCode.

Answer (score 1):

**In Flutter App**
*to upload app **APK** in the **play store** you have to follow some **steps:***

1. Go to **Project -> app-> build.gradle**

> increase the **flutterVersionCode=2** and **flutterVersionName=2.0**

[image]

2. Go to **pubspec.yaml** file

> increase the version to **1.0.1+2**

[image]

*finally build your apk `flutter build apk --release` and upload it successfully*

**this is the updated version of apk in *play store***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can only if you have the KEY.jks file

Answer (score -2):

No, you cannot upload the generated app from Flutter to play store. You can build and create apk file for the application using Flutter. but to publish it you need to go to Google Play Console.

Comment: no i am asking second update i made it in flutter not in android studio.